# CSS - Insert div into middle of unordered list

Tags: html, css

I have a menu, which is in fact an unordered list:

```
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">O nás</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Místo</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Program</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Svatební dary</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Fotogalerie</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">formulá</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">na Potvrzení účasti</a></li>
        </ul>
```

I don't know the number of items in the menu beforehand, the menu is generated dynammicaly. I need to display a div with logo in the middle of the menu, with the same amount of items on sides of the logo (or, if the no. of items in menu is ie. 5, display 2 on left and 3 on right)

```
            <div>
               <a href="#">
                <div class="logo">Filip a Denisa</div>
                <div id="slogan">21. Srpna 2014</div>
               </a>
            </div>
```

Is this scenario possible to do with CSS3, or do I need to use either CSS + JS or PHP to generate the menu right away as needed?

Comment: You probably have to do it in JS or backend.

Comment: The way you are generating menu through any sort of calculation, there you can calculate number of LI's in UL. And can insert that DIV at certain point.
Yes can be done with JS

Comment: You should also be aware that you cannot put a div inside a `ul`. It would have to be wrapped in an `li`.

Comment: This may sound rude, but I fail to understand why you believe this can be done in CSS.

Comment: If the menu is created dynaicaly, what ever that process is should handle the insert. Also note @Paulie_D s comment. You will either need to have more than one list or wrap the insert in a `li`

Comment: Depending on how they're all positioned, you could fake it. We need a lot more detail to decide if that's the case though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can only be done after the page is loaded by javascript or Jquery my friend, here is a working example in Jquery, hope that helps:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var liCount = $(".nav.navbar-nav li").length,
    DivCont = '<li>'+
                '<div>'+
                  '<a href="#">'+
                    '<div class="logo">Filip a Denisa</div>'+
                    '<div id="slogan">21. Srpna 2014</div>'+
                  '</a>'+
                '</div>'+
              '</li>';

if(liCount % 2==0){
    var halfCount = liCount / 2;
    $(".nav.navbar-nav li:eq("+ halfCount +")").before(DivCont);
}else{
    var halfCount = Math.floor(liCount / 2);
    $(".nav.navbar-nav li:eq("+ halfCount +")").before(DivCont);
}

});
```

And here is the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qe8dqapa/

Comment: It's jQuery, not Jquery :)

Comment: I apologize for the mistake :)